# Merge arrays containing shared associative keys without overwriting each other

Tags: php, arrays, array-merge

I am working with multiple APIs returning data as flat arrays. All of these APIs are returning arrays with shared keys.

For example:

Returning data from API A,B and C:

```
$a = array(1 => "abc", 2 => "def");
$b = array(1 => "ghi", 2 => "jkl");
$c = array(1 => "mno", 2 => "pqr");
```

All of these arrays have repeated numeric keys. My requirement is a single array without losing values due to key collisions.

Required outcome:

```
array(
    "abc",
    "def",
    "ghi",
    "jkl",
    "mno",
    "pqr"
);
```

I tried `array_merge()` function but it overwrites the duplicated key and `array_merge_recursive()` function accumulate all repeated key into another array.

Comment: Your example seems at odds with your requirement as it does overwrite the keys just like `array_merge()` would, ignoring the index starting at 1.

Comment: I used `array_merge()` with your variable arrays and it worked out fine without overwriting (starts at `0` instead of `1` however).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.......

```
$a=array(1=>"abc",2=>"def");
$b=array(1=>"ghi",2=>"jkl");
$c=array(1=>"mno",2=>"pqr");

$d = array();

foreach($a as $arr){
 array_push($d, $arr);
}

foreach($b as $arr){
 array_push($d, $arr);
}

foreach($c as $arr){
 array_push($d, $arr);
}
print_r($d);
```

Output is

```
Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => ghi [3] => jkl [4] => mno [5] => pqr )
```

I also tried your example with array merge & it gave me following o/p.

```
Array ( [0] => abc [1] => def [2] => ghi [3] => jkl [4] => mno [5] => pqr )
```

Comment: Thanks Rohit, array_push  method works for me, though array_merge works in numeric key but won't work with alphanumeric key.

Answer (score 1):

This is a fairly short way to create an array containing all the values regardless of their keys:

```
$z = array_merge(
    array_values($a),
    array_values($b),
    array_values($c)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) or [array_merge_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php).

For array_merge if you are using string keys the values will be overwritten meaning there will be only one value for that key on the output array.

For array_merge_recursive if you are using numeric keys the value will be overwritten meaning there will be only one value for that key in the output array

Answer (score 0):

Because your keys are all numeric, you can "splat-pack" the data by using variadic expressions inside of a new array.  This is a one-liner that requires absolutely no function calls to generate the desired data structure.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FLRea))

```
$a = [1 => "abc", 2 => "def"];
$b = [1 => "ghi", 2 => "jkl"];
$c = [1 => "mno", 2 => "pqr"];

var_export(
    [...$a, ...$b, ...$c]
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'abc',
  1 => 'def',
  2 => 'ghi',
  3 => 'jkl',
  4 => 'mno',
  5 => 'pqr',
)
```

`array_merge()` provides the same results. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/2oCr9))

```
var_export(array_merge($a, $b, $c));
```

And three language constructs will do the same thing. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/UkCAE))

```
$result = [];
foreach ($a as $result[]);
foreach ($b as $result[]);
foreach ($c as $result[]);
var_export($result);
```

---

Alternatively, if you want the keys in the merged result array to start from 1, you can use variadic expressions inside of a single `array_push()` call. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/FSkAa))

```
array_push($a, ...$b, ...$c);
var_export($a);
```

Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'abc',
  2 => 'def',
  3 => 'ghi',
  4 => 'jkl',
  5 => 'mno',
  6 => 'pqr',
)
```

You must not use array union operators, because they will destroy elements due to key collisions. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/RdEl3))

```
var_export($a + $b + $c);
```

Bad Output:

```
array (
  1 => 'abc',
  2 => 'def',
)
```